# how to append a value to a variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am getting a variable value from properties and I am able to access in sh file.
but I am unable to append another value to that variable.

Kindly suggest.

```
$ echo "Build ID from properties:"$BUILD_ID
Build ID from properties: abcd_v6_c1

$ echo " num----------------" build_${BUILD_ID}.zip
.zip---------------- build_abcd_v6_c1
```

Kindly suggest how to append **.zip** value.

Comment: You may have a special char at the end of your `$BUILD_ID` variable that has undesirable effect on output (maybe a `^M` or `^A`). You can check with `cat -A <<< "$BUILD_ID"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have a Windows [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) in your `$BUILD_ID` variable.

To check, try this command (the carriage return will be visible as a `^M`) :

```
cat -A <<< "$BUILD_ID"
```

In your terminal,you can try this (to get the `^M` char, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) :

```
$ BUILD_ID="585548979^M"
$ echo ${BUILD_ID}text
```

The result should be :

```
text48979
```

You can clean your variable with a Bash parameter substitution :

```
$ ID=${BUILD_ID%$'\r'}
$ echo ${ID}text
585548979text
```

Comment: @chepner Thanks for you edit. Note that `${BUILD_ID/%$'\r'/}` is also valid, as it replaces shortest string of `$'\r' from back with nothing. But it's simpler as you suggest  to just shorten the string.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I had actually read that as `${BUILD_ID%/$'\r'/}` (transposing the initial `/` and the `%`, which is why I thought it was wrong).

Comment: Nicely done (note that `cat -A` is a _GNU_ extension; `cat -et` would work with BSD/OSX `cat` too; `sed -n l` is a POSIX-compliant alternative).

Answer (score 9):

Let's say we have a variable`var1=value`.
If I want to add some text to the beginning of the variable I can do:

```
var1="some text${var1}"
```

If I want to add some text to the end, it will be:

```
var1="${var1}some text"
```

Answer (score 0):

This following way works for me. My .sh file has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
. /usr/test/build.properties
echo $BUILD_ID
echo "num----------------" build_${BUILD_ID}.zip
```

Comment: what is the o/p I am getting the below o/p 
.zip---------------- build_abcd_v6_c1

but I need build_abcd_v6_c1.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `assignment(=)` operator to append text.

```
a=don
b=$a" jon"
echo $b #==>don jon
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

Able to fix the issue.. it's because of ^M thanks @Kenavoz now I am getting proper ID and able to proceed with the o/p.

Change:BUILD_ID=${ID%$'\r'}

Thanks,
Sampath A